# How do I select the 2nd script after a specific child div?

Tags: javascript, html

Let me explain with this sample code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>...</header>
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>

    <!--header scripts inserted here-->

    <div id="content">...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>

    <!--footer scripts inserted here-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
    <div id="something">...</div>
    <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

here's what I'm trying to do: (JQuery for example only as real JS is less readable)

```
$(`
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
`).insertAfter("div#wrapper > div#content + script:eq(2)");
```

Of course though the selector in `insertAfter` doesn't work...
How exactly do I make it work??

And yes, the position of the scripts are very specific. (in the body of course)

My goal is to run the example script in the head to insert the sub-scripts into the page before everything in the body gets loaded.
The header is loaded before the footer, and the order of the inserted scripts matters greatly between them.

I've also found out, not every page has those particular 2 scripts I'm trying to insert after so the insertion can happen after the div in question.

Comment: Wait, what? You are using `<script>`s this way? It won't work.

Comment: Please describe your objective, because @PraveenKumar is right--there's no way that'll work.

Comment: my objective is described in the sample code...
so the jquery script is probably wrong... but you get the idea

Comment: you can create html elements in jquery selectors... though not sure about blocks

Comment: Please check your console for script error first

Comment: I'm asking how to insert a block of code (as shown in the jquery selector) into the location described by the comment... I will do error checking once I can insert them.

Comment: ok of you're going to downvote then please explain why... I think what I want is pretty clear...

Comment: The only reason (I can think of) for trying to do this is dependencies. The order of <script> tags affect the order by which they are loaded and thus their dependencies. If you manage to insert new script-sources AFTER the page has loaded how do you propose to tell the browser that it should reload the scripts that are defined after your newly inserted script-sources?

Comment: hmm... alright, good point... well what I'm doing is inserting that example script in the head while inserting the extensions into the body... is it possible to make sure everything loads as expected??

Comment: alright, edited with better intention as to what's going on.

Comment: edited and removed the JQuery tag as what I want to do is possible with JS only (inserting scripts just in time before DOM element load)

Answer (score 3):

Upvoted Phase Phusion. This doesn't make sense to me either. I'm pretty sure that many people here would suggest you some good solutions for what you intend to do if you explain your goal. But for fun sake I'll give you a snippet to play with:

```
 $(
    '\<script type="text/javascript" src="..."\>\<\/script\>' +
    '\<script type="text/javascript" src="..."\>\<\/script\>'
 ).insertAfter( '#wrapper > #content ~ script:eq(1)' )
```

You need to escape the string you pass to jQuery, so the browser knows that's a string and no HTML when rendering the page.

Good luck :)

Comment: Phase Phusion actually pointed out something I didn't see, and I up-voted him myself... but thanks, I'll give that a try. :)

Comment: this didn't work for me, though I've found something that might if I can figure out how to make scripts wait for initialization when a particular DOM element is hit.

Answer (score 1):

well, after not being able to find anything to check that the DOM element `"div#wrapper"` exists before it's content loads, I've decided to add 2 scripts to the insertion locations, instead of the head, to load the sub-scripts from a "current" perspective.

Reference code: (same in both js files aside from loaded scripts)

```
$(this).append(`
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script>
`); // found out the mime-type actually detriments your html and isn't needed.
```

while it loads the sub-scripts properly, 
the added script tags don't show up in the DOM (elements tab)

Comment: this worked perfectly, all of my referenced scripts within the 2 scripts load up with no issues :)